# How to fill missing values based on categorica

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have one feature called price which contains some missing values. I have another column 'points' which does not have missing value but it is highly correlated with price. I want to fill the missing values of price by the average price based on points. For example if the point value of record is 16 then missing value of price should be filled by average price of all records having points value as 16. I am using Pandas. I tried scikit learn library but it does not have such functionality. Please help

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that might help you. It uses linear regression to predict the price from the points, based only on the non-missing data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
myData=pd.DataFrame({'price':[10,20,30,40,50,None,70], 'points':[12,18,22,42,53,62,89]})
model = LinearRegression()
y = myData[~myData['price'].isnull()]['price']
x = np.array(myData[~myData['price'].isnull()]['points']).reshape((-1, 1))
model.fit(x,y)
myData['price'][myData['price'].isnull()] = model.predict(np.array(myData[myData['price'].isnull()]['points']).reshape((-1, 1)))
```